# TeXstudio not correctly working on Mac OS X

Tags: pdf, texstudio, sourcecode

Yesterday I installed TeXstudio on my Ubuntu system. I realized it has nice functions like "jump to PDF" (goes to PDF and highlights the marked text) and "go to source code" (goes to the source code of that part that was clicked in the PDF):

Now I installed TeXstudio under Mac OS X, and those functions do not work. Strangely it was also configured in a way that external viewers were used to show the PDF. I changed everything to "internal PDF viewer", but still these nice "jump function" don't work.

What do I have to change (in the preferences), so that I use those function? Or is it not possible to use them within Mac OS X?

Comment: Have you the synctex command included in your path? For me with "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex the jump-function works fine

Comment: `-synctex=1` was there for `xelatex` and `lualatex`, but not for `latex` and `pdflatex`. I added it, and now it works. Please write an answer, so that I can accept it,...

Comment: synctex sometimes has (or had, not sure if this is solved completely) problems if there is whitespace in the path or filename of your tex document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[turning previous comment into answer]

Add -synctex=1 to your path, e.g.

> "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Then the jump-function should work.